# About Regular Expression

Tags: automata

Set={a,b} and L7:"All words that begin with an a and end with a b" is given L7 can be defined by

a(a+b)*b

What is the meaning of "+" ?
And,
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a       # first letter is always 'a'
(a+b)*  # zero or more sequence of letters 'a' or 'b' [one letter at time]
b       # last letter is always 'b'
```

Here `+` means `or` and then consequently, we have the below results:

```
ab
abb
abbb
aaab
abbbb
aaaab
abbbbb
aaaaab
.....
```

Comment: Thanks,
What is the symbol of AND ?

Comment: @HakanHakyemez there is no "and" you concatenate by putting two REs together. read the book?

Comment: @HakanHakyemez `AND` here means `(ab)*` that will produce these strings: `ab`, `aabb`, `aababb`, ...

Comment: No. I didn't read books about aoutomata theory. I'm trying slides.